# HoHOA behaves differently when values are pushed

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

I have the following data:

```
eya XLOC_000445_Change:10.3_q:0.003 atonal1
six XLOC_00099_Change:70.0_q:0.095  atonal1
six-eya XLOC_0234324_Change:19.8_q:0.05 atonal1
eya XLOC_00010_Change:6.5_q:0.22    c-myc
six XLOC_025437_Change:1.1_q:0.018  c-myc
six-eya XLOC_001045_Change:2.3_q:0.0001 c-myc
eya XLOC_000115_Change:7.3_q:0.03   ezrin
six XLOC_000001_Change:7.9_q:0.00006    ezrin
six-eya XLOC_0234322_Change:9.0_q:0.0225    ezrin
six-eya XLOC_091345_Change:9.3_q:0.005  slc12a2
eya XLOC_000445_Change:9.9_q:0.3    atonal1
six XLOC_00099_Change:7.0_q:0.95    atonal1
six-eya XLOC_0234324_Change:9.8_q:0.5   atonal1
```

And have tried building a HoHoA as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

**Method 1: Pushing array values onto HoH:**

```
while (<$input>) { 
    chomp;
    push @xloc, $1 if ($_ =~ /(XLOC_\d+)/);
    push @change_val, $1 if ($_ =~ /Change:(-?\d+\.\d+|-?inf)/);
    push @q_value, $1 if ($_ =~ /q:(\d+\.\d+)/);
    my @split = split('\t');            
    push @condition, $split[0];
    push @gene, $split[2];
}           
push @{ $experiment{$gene[$_]}{$condition[$_]} }, [ $xloc[$_], $change_val[$_], $q_value[$_] ] for 0 .. $#change_val;
```

**Method 2: Assigning values to HoHoA on the fly:**

```
while (<$input>) { 
    chomp;
    my $xloc = $1 if ($_ =~ /(XLOC_\d+)/);
    my $change = $1 if ($_ =~ /Change:(-?\d+\.\d+|-?inf)/);
    my $q_value = $1 if ($_ =~ /q:(\d+\.\d+)/);
    my @split = split('\t');
    my $condition = $split[0];
    my $gene = $split[2];
    $experiment{$gene}{$condition} = [ $xloc, $change, $q_value ];
}
```

Both work fine - insofar as I get the data structure I want. However, only the first method (pushing) ensures that genes that exist as duplicates (in this case `atonal1`) are represented twice in the HoHoA.

My downstream code was originally made to handle HoHoA built in the second fashion, and I can't for the life of me work out why both approaches are handled differently in the follwing code:

**Downstream code:**

```
my (%change, %seen, $xloc, $change_val, $q_value);
for my $gene (sort keys %experiment) {
     for my $condition (sort keys %{$experiment{$gene}}) {
         $seen{$gene}++; # Counts for each occurrence of gene 
         if ( (not exists $change{$gene}) || (abs $change{$gene} < abs $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[1]) ) { # Has a larger change value
             $change{$gene} = $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[1];
         }               
    }
}
print Dumper \%change;
```

When I run the above code on either approach I get:

Output for **method 1**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'atonal1' => [
                         'XLOC_0234324',
                         '9.8',
                         '0.5'
                       ],
          'c-myc' => undef,
          'ezrin' => undef,
          'slc12a2' => undef,
        };
```

Output for **method 2**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'atonal1' => '9.9', # i.e. the largest change value for each condition/gene
          'c-myc' => '6.5',
          'ezrin' => '9.0',
          'slc12a2' => '9.3',
        };
```

What I want is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'atonal1' => [
                          '9.9',
                          '70.0' # This is the difference - i.e the both values are added to the hash `%change`
                       ], 
          'c-myc' => '6.5',
          'ezrin' => '9.0',
          'slc12a2' => '9.3',
        };
```

I have no idea what's creating the difference

**UPDATE**

I'll post the Dumper output for `%experiment` after values have been pushed on using **Method 1**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'atonal1' => {
                         'eya' => [
                                    [
                                      'XLOC_000445',
                                      '10.3',
                                      '0.003'
                                    ],
                                    [
                                      'XLOC_000445',
                                      '9.9',
                                      '0.3'
                                    ]
                                  ],
                         'six' => [
                                    [
                                      'XLOC_00099',
                                      '70.0',
                                      '0.095'
                                    ],
                                    [
                                      'XLOC_00099',
                                      '7.0',
                                      '0.95'
                                    ]
                                  ],
                         'six-eya' => [
                                        [
                                          'XLOC_0234324',
                                          '19.8',
                                          '0.05'
                                        ],
                                        [
                                          'XLOC_0234324',
                                          '9.8',
                                          '0.5'
                                        ]
                                      ]
                       },
          'c-myc' => {
                       'eya' => [
                                  [
                                    'XLOC_00010',
                                    '6.5',
                                    '0.22'
                                  ]
                                ],
                       'six' => [
                                  [
                                    'XLOC_025437',
                                    '1.1',
                                    '0.018'
                                  ]
                                ],
                       'six-eya' => [
                                      [
                                        'XLOC_001045',
                                        '2.3',
                                        '0.0001'
                                      ]
                                    ]
                     },

          'ezrin' => {
                       'eya' => [
                                  [
                                    'XLOC_000115',
                                    '7.3',
                                    '0.03'
                                  ]
                                ],
                       'six' => [
                                  [
                                    'XLOC_000001',
                                    '7.9',
                                    '0.00006'
                                  ]
                                ],
                       'six-eya' => [
                                      [
                                        'XLOC_0234322',
                                        '9.0',
                                        '0.0225'
                                      ]
                                    ]
                     },
          'slc12a2' => {
                         'six-eya' => [
                                        [
                                          'XLOC_091345',
                                          '9.3',
                                          '0.005'
                                        ]
                                      ]
                       },

        };
```

Comment: Your desired output has two equal keys `'atonal1'`. That's not possible in a hash. Keys must be unique.

Comment: `... if ($_ =~ /regex/)` is more cogently and idiomatically written as simply `... if /regex/`.

Comment: Yes - of course you're right. However I'm pushing them onto an array - see updated desired output...

Answer (score 4):

Let's take your data and reformat it a bit. I'm not saying this is the way you need to format your data. I'm just doing it this way to get a better understanding of what it represents:

```
GENE      XLOC                  CHANGE   Q VALUE   CONDITION
========  ====================  =======  ========  ==========
eya       XLOC_000445_Change:   10.3_q:  0.003     atonal1
six       XLOC_00099_Change:    70.0_q:  0.095     atonal1
six-eya   XLOC_0234324_Change:  19.8_q:  0.05      atonal1
eya       XLOC_00010_Change:    6.5_q:   0.22      c-myc
six       XLOC_025437_Change:   1.1_q:   0.018     c-myc
six-eya   XLOC_001045_Change:   2.3_q:   0.0001    c-myc
eya       XLOC_000115_Change:   7.3_q:   0.03      ezrin
six       XLOC_000001_Change:   7.9_q:   0.00006   ezrin
six-eya   XLOC_0234322_Change:  9.0_q:   0.0225    ezrin
six-eya   XLOC_091345_Change:   9.3_q:   0.005     slc12a2
eya       XLOC_000445_Change:   9.9_q:   0.3       atonal1
six       XLOC_00099_Change:    7.0_q:   0.95      atonal1
six-eya   XLOC_0234324_Change:  9.8_q:   0.5       atonal1
```

Are my column assumptions correct?

First, I recommend that you use `split` to split up your values instead of regular expressions. Do this on a line-by-line basis. Perl is pretty efficient at optimization. 90% of programming is debugging and supporting your program. Trying to be efficient by compressing multiple steps into a single step just make things harder to understand with very little value returned in optimization.

Let's take each line, and break it out:

```
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $gene, $more_data, $condition ) = split /\s+/, $line;
```

At this point:

```
$gene = 'eye'
$more_data = 'XLOC_000445_Change:10.3_q:0.003';
$condition = 'atonal1`    # I'm not sure what this is...
```

Now, we can split out `$more_data`:

```
my ( $xloc, $change, $q_value ) = split /:/, $more_data;
$xloc =~ s/^XLOC_//;
$change =~ s/_q$//;
```

Now we have:

```
$xloc = '000445';
$change = '10.3';
$q_value = '0.003';
```

Does this make more sense?

One of your problems is you're attempting to store data in a very, very complex structure without really thinking about what that data represents.

Let's say your data is this:

- a *gene* may contain multiple *conditions*,
- Each *gene-condition* combination can have a *result*.
- This result contains an *xloc*, *q_value*, and *change*.

That means your data should look like this:

```
$experiment{$gene}->{$condition}->{XLOC}    = $xloc;
$experiment{$gene}->{$condition}->{Q_VALUE} = $q_value;
$experiment{$gene}->{$condition}->{CHANGE}  = $change;
```

However, I see gene = `eya`, condition = `atonal1` twice in your list. Maybe you need something more along the lines of this:

- a *gene* may contain multiple *conditions*,
- Each *gene-condition* combination can have multiple *results*.
- Each result contains an *xloc*, *q_value*, and *change*.

If that's the case, your data structure should look something like this:

```
$experment{$gene}->{$condition}->[0]->{XLOC}    = $xloc;
$experment{$gene}->{$condition}->[0]->{Q_VALUE} = $q_value;
$experment{$gene}->{$condition}->[0]->{CHANGE}  = $change;
```

---

This isn't an answer. I'm just trying to get a handle on what your data is and what you are trying to store in that data. Once we have that settled, I can help you with the rest of your program.

Let me know if my understanding of what your data represents is accurate. Add a comment to this answer, and update your question a bit.

Once I know I'm on the right track, I'll show you how you can more easily manage this structure and keep track of everything in it.

Now that I knew I was on the right track, the solution was fairly simple: Object Oriented Programming!

Let me explain: Each experiment consists of a Gene-Condition pair. This is what I key my experiments on.

I create a `Local::Condition` for each of these Gene-Condition pairs. Inside of this I store my array of results.

My results contain three item.

---

## Behold: The Answer!

What I decided to do is to create a *results object*. This object contains the XLoc, Change, and Q Value of that result. By packing my results into an object, I have fewer issues trying to keep track of it.

So what we have is this:

- We have *experiments*.
- Each _experiment consists of a gene/condition pair which we key our experiments on.
- Each gene/condition experiment consists of an array of results.

Now, it's a lot easier to keep track of what is going on. For each line, I create a `Local::Result` type of object that contains the *set of results* of that gene/condition pair.

So, all I have to do is push my results onto that gene/condition array which represents my *set of results*

```
#
# Create a Result for this experiment
#

my $result = Local::Result->new( $xloc, $change, $q_value );

#
# Push this result onto your $gene/condition experiment
#
push @{ $experiments{$gene}->{$condition} }, $result;
```

Note my syntax here is very spelled out. I have a hash called `%experiments` that are keyed by *Genes*. Each gene contains *Conditions* for that gene. This Gene/Condition pair is an array of *results*.

Object Oriented syntax can be a bit complex to get use to, but there is an excellent [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) in the Perl documentation. By using object oriented programming, you group together details that you otherwise must track.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my %experiments;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my ($condition, $more_data, $gene) = split /\s+/, $line;

    my ($xloc, $change, $q_value) = split /:/, $more_data;
    $xloc   =~ s/^XLOC_(.*)_Change/$1/;
    $change =~ s/_q$//;

    my $result = Local::Result->new( $xloc, $change, $q_value );
    push @{ $experiments{$gene}->{$condition} }, $result;
}

printf "%-10.10s  %-10.10s  %10.10s  %-4s  %-7s\n\n",
    "Gene", "Condition", "XLoc", "Chng", "Q Value";
for my $gene ( sort keys %experiments ) {
    for my $condition ( sort keys %{ $experiments{$gene} } ) {
        for my $result ( @{ $experiments{$gene}->{$condition} } ) {
            printf "%-10.10s  %-10.10s  %10.10s  %-4.1f  %-7.1f\n",
                $gene, $condition, $result->xloc, $result->change, $result->q_value;
        }
    }
}

package Local::Result;

sub new {
    my $class       = shift;
    my $xloc        = shift;
    my $change      = shift;
    my $q_value     = shift;

    my $self        = {};
    bless $self, $class;

    $self->xloc($xloc);
    $self->change($change);
    $self->q_value($q_value);

    return $self;
}

sub xloc {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $xloc        = shift;

    if ( defined $xloc ) {
        $self->{XLOC} = $xloc;
    }
    return $self->{XLOC};
}

sub change {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $change      = shift;

    if ( defined $change ) {
        $self->{CHANGE} = $change;
    }
    return $self->{CHANGE};
}

sub q_value {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $q_value     = shift;

    if ( defined $q_value ) {
        $self->{Q_VALUE} = $q_value;
    }
    return $self->{Q_VALUE};
}

package main;


__DATA__
eya XLOC_000445_Change:10.3_q:0.003 atonal1
six XLOC_00099_Change:70.0_q:0.095  atonal1
six-eya XLOC_0234324_Change:19.8_q:0.05 atonal1
eya XLOC_00010_Change:6.5_q:0.22    c-myc
six XLOC_025437_Change:1.1_q:0.018  c-myc
six-eya XLOC_001045_Change:2.3_q:0.0001 c-myc
eya XLOC_000115_Change:7.3_q:0.03   ezrin
six XLOC_000001_Change:7.9_q:0.00006    ezrin
six-eya XLOC_0234322_Change:9.0_q:0.0225    ezrin
six-eya XLOC_091345_Change:9.3_q:0.005  slc12a2
eya XLOC_000445_Change:9.9_q:0.3    atonal1
six XLOC_00099_Change:7.0_q:0.95    atonal1
six-eya XLOC_0234324_Change:9.8_q:0.5   atonal1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which I've edited to better reflect what I'm dealing with. Also see my update

Comment: Okay, so I have the Gene and Condition columns mixed up? Otherwise, I have the data correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes - See my updated Dumper output to see exactly what I have

Comment: Jesus! This is going to be really useful for me as I venture into the world of object-oriented programming. Very grateful for the effort on your part. I'll come back again once I've played around with your suggestions - thanks!

Comment: I'm still at a loss to understand why referring to an element in the HoHoA using `$experiment{$gene}{$condition}[1]` works differently in each case...

Comment: @FlyingFrog I prefer to use $experiment{$gene}->{$condition}->[1] because it is explicit in what I am looking at. `${experiment{$gene}` is a reference to a hash (The `->`) and ${condition} is a key in that hash. That hash reference contains an array reference (The `->`), and I want the 2nd element (`[1]`) of that array. I'm still not 100% comfortable with this. I feel the data structure is just too convoluted, and should be further objectified. Maybe `$experiments{gene}` should be an object. I tried making `$condition` an object that contained an array of `resuits`, but wasn't happy with that.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've identified the source of the problem: By pushing onto the HoH I create a AoA (see data dumper output for gene `atonal`), so when assigning to new hash as follows: `$change{$gene} = $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[1]` I'm really only adding the associated info for `atonal` - as it's the only gene that exists at that level of the AoA. This is fixed by looping through dereferenced values as such: `for my $values (@{$experiment{$gene{$condition} }){ my ($xloc, $change_val, $q_value) = @$values; }`

Comment: @FlyingFrog This is one of the reasons to use Object Oriented Perl (OOP). When you have these very complex structures, keeping them straight throughout the entire program can become very difficult. OOP removes that burden. You no longer care about the structure since OOP will handle it for you.